# Set the color of the active section/subsection in the navigation bar (beamer)

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I want to keep the active section highlighted meanwhile navigating on its subsections. Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{Title of the Presentation}
\author{Author Author}
\date{22-10-2016}

% theme
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[default]
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.1.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.1.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.2.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.2.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.1.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.1.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.2.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.2.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I navigate to frame 1.1.1

Obtained (navigation bar)

[image]

Desired (navigation bar)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed one line in the definition of the navigation bar, you can finde it marked with `% HERE`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% theme
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\makeatletter
\def\insertverticalnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{%
    \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##5=\c@part%
      \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
      \hbox to #1{{%
        \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=0\relax%
              {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
            \else%
              \ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}% HERE
              \fi%
            \fi%
          \else
            {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax\fi}%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
    \def\beamer@subsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
       \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##4}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0\relax%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    \def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionheadnumber{##4}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{##6}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\ifnum\c@subsubsection=##4\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##5}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=##4%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}}%
              \else
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    %\beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax%
    \dohead%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\title{Title of the Presentation}
\author{Author Author}
\date{22-10-2016}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[default]
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.1.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.1.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.2.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 1.2.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.1.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.1.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.2.1}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frame 2.2.2}
this is a frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to be a surgeon. It works like a charm.